# Huge files(~1Gb) into array to manipulate

Tags: c#, arrays, memory, scripting, .net-6.0

In this weekend, I have wanted to enhance my [Apple's right click dictionaries](https://preview.redd.it/5k58ya47u8l71.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=002f20318b7365ed13a301e955336e34cb019c6a). [It has to be in some determined format](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/schema/schema.html)(has nothing to do with this part of the question). For example, Oxford dictionary shows, when clicked, `-ed, -ing, -s` forms as *bare verb form*, but not same for Collin's. To integrate it, I need to add `-ed, -ing, -s` forms of verb words.

Example word `brace` in Oxford dict is defined like

```
<d:entry id="_4ma" d:title="brace">
<d:index d:value="brace" d:title="brace"/><d:index d:value="braced" d:title="brace"/><d:index d:value="braces" d:title="brace"/><d:index d:value="bracing" d:title="brace"/><a name="49f1b05b3013431b8dbb9ff989c2755a_brace" nattr="head-jump-entry-flag"></a>
```

As you can see, there are `<d:index d:value="` multiple entries.

In `Collin's`,

```
<d:entry id="_379" d:title="brace">
<d:index d:value="brace" d:title="brace"/><div id="collins_english_dictionary">
```

As you can see again, there are no the following entries unlike that of `Oxford`,

```
<d:index d:value="braced" d:title="brace"/><d:index d:value="braces" d:title="brace"/><d:index d:value="bracing" d:title="brace"/>
```

What the following code snippet does is to find missing entries of every word which are in the destination dictionary(`Collin's`) and make the following format ultimately. (Of no importance of being duplicated.)

```
<d:entry id="_379" d:title="brace">
<d:index d:value="braced" d:title="brace"/><d:index d:value="braces" d:title="brace"/><d:index d:value="bracing" d:title="brace"/>
<d:index d:value="brace" d:title="brace"/><div id="collins_english_dictionary">
```

The problem is that the files are too big one of them is of almost 500MB size while the other is of 1Gb size(almost 4 million lines Oxford, 120 thousand lines in Collins due to being collapsed tags). The IDE or the compiler leaves in the lurch before completion successfully. How can we succeed?

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var source = "/Users/soner/Desktop/Oxford Advanced Learner Dictionary/Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.xml";
var lines = File.ReadLines(source);

var destination = "/Users/soner/Desktop/Collins COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary/Collins COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary.xml";
var destinationLines = File.ReadLines(destination).ToList();

var sourceLines = lines.ToList();
int destIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sourceLines.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (sourceLines[i].Contains("<d:entry id="))
    {
        ++i; // we are almost sure searched part is immediately in the next line, if not q==-1 cotinue;
        var aTagLine = sourceLines[i];
        var q = aTagLine.IndexOf("<a name", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (q == -1) continue;

        var wantedPart = aTagLine[..q];
        // if there is no form of the word being searched -ing -s or -ed tags
        if(wantedPart.Split("d:index").Length <= 2) continue;

        // the word to be searched for
        var word = Regex.Matches(wantedPart, "(?<=d:title=\").*?(?=\")")[0].ToString();

        int memoriedIndex = destIndex;
        // from now on we are in destination dictionary to add missing entities -ed,-ing etc. forms
        for (; destIndex < destinationLines.Count; destIndex++)
        {
            if (destinationLines[destIndex].Contains("<d:entry id=") && destinationLines[destIndex].Contains($"{word}\">"))
            {
                destinationLines[destIndex] = $"{destinationLines[destIndex]}\n{wantedPart}";
                break;
            }

            // I need this one because
            // what if destination dictionary doesn't have the word searched in source dictionary
            // it needs go some steps backward to go on
            if (destIndex - memoriedIndex > 100)
            {
                destIndex = memoriedIndex;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("/Users/soner/Desktop/soner.xml", destinationLines);
```

Comment: Maybe some kind of radix tree structure. Regex is going to be dog slow either way even if you can get it loaded.

Comment: Since you're working with two xml documents, it might make more sense to use XmlReader or similar, and then you can query attributes directly instead of `.Contains, .IndexOf .Split` and regex. Probably some preprocessing would help, for example, list of unique words in a hashset so you don't iterate over every single line when a word match isn't found.

Comment: Since you are only looking at one line at a time, the simplest change is to avoid `lines.ToList()`, and instead `foreach(var line in lines)`. And write the destination lines one at a time as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should definitely work with filestreams/stringstreams and ensure that async file IO is enabled. Do not read the whole file at once. Additionally, you can do all text-processing and datastructure building on separate threads.

You should definitely transform the raw xml data into a more usable data structure (in memory, or possibly something else) optimized for your use case, before working with it, as was already mentioned. I'm not gonna go into detail which one, I didn't look at your use case too closely.

You would have to experiment a little which one's faster, processing using XmlReader or regex. Usually, I would always recommend XmlReader, except in very simple and performance critical situations, when something else might be more efficient. Make sure to instantiate the regex only once (don't use the statig methods) and set the `Compiled` option.

These are just *some* thoughts to get you started, not a complete answer.